# Adding all existing AWX inventories to a new group

Tags: ansible

I have a multiple inventories created in AWX. For admin/reporting purpose, I need to execute a playbook in all hosts ( Multiple inventories). Is there a way to execute a playbook across all existing inventories in one go. Any quick help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Uday

Comment: It is recommend to have environment specific inventories so that no job runs accidentally to some other host that are not part of the env. The best you can do is choose prompt on launch option. so that you can select an inventory everytime you run the job.

Comment: Agreed, I have it that way. I have 75 separate inventories. Now my problem is, I want to pull a report on all the hosts across all 75 inventories, How can I do that in one shot ?

Answer (score 1):

Use smart inventory,

1. Create a smart inventory in awx
2. In the 'SMART HOST FILTER' give '.' and click search
3. Then click save
4. The new smart inventory will have all the hosts containing '.'
5. Target your Job to the new smart inventory created

[More info on smart inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/inventories.html#smart-inventories)

[More info on what search patterns you can use](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/search_sort.html)